# Add one element to ObservableCollection / DataGrid when it becomes empty

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, observablecollection

I have an `ObservableCollection<MyItem>` called `MyObservableCollection`. Its items are displayed in a `DataGrid`. What I need is when all the rows are deleted from the `DataGrid`, one `MyItem` with default values should be added back.

The following will not work if I delete all the rows at once. It will work when I delete them one-by-one.

```
void DataGrid_UnloadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
{
    myDataGrid.Items.Refresh();
    if (0 == MyObservableCollection.Count)
    {
        MyObservableCollection.Add(new MyItem());
    }
}
```

Also I can't use the `CollectionChanged` event handler, as the collection cannot be manipulated from that one (would cause an infinite loop).

**How can I achieved the above mentioned functionality?**

Comment: Could you explain what you exactly mean by `Also I can't use the CollectionChanged event handler, as the collection cannot be manipulated from that one (would cause an infinite loop`? What's wrong with your current code?

Comment: Dont manipulate UI events like this, for data management. Data is Data. UI is UI. Learn MVVM.

Comment: Infinite loop will occur when you `Add` or `remove` **UnConditionally**. IMO it is straight forward to use `CollectionChanged` event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subscribe to the `CollectionChanged` event. Since the `Collection` cannot be modified in the `CollectionChanged` event, you can use the `Dispatcher` class and modify it. See the sample code below.

```
    void MyObservableCollection_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove || e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset)
        {
            if (MyObservableCollection.Count == 0)
            {
                Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
                    {
                        MyObservableCollection.Add(new MyItem());
                    }), null);
            }
        }
    }
```